# User sql column a if b is 0 else use b

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have an sql query that select sum of product price and quantity. I want to use cost price to sum it if the cost price is not zero..
my sql query is thus:

```
SELECT SUM(price*quantity) as sum FROM `table` WHERE invoice = '1';
```

the same table has (id,price,cost_price,quantity), the aim is to use cost_price if it is not zero else use price.

so if am looking for a query like this:

```
SELECT SUM( ((cost_price == 0) ? price : cost_price) *quantity) as sum FROM `table` WHERE invoice = '1';
```

Comment: What RDBMs are you using? (*Tag it in your question*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also do this... (SQL Server)

```
SELECT SUM(COALESCE(NULLIF(cost_price,0),price) * quantity) AS sum 
FROM [table]
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is achieved by a *conditional aggregate*:

```
SUM( (CASE WHEN cost_price = 0 THEN price ELSE cost_price END) * quantity) as sum
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a case expression for the logic like below. The syntax below should work in most DBMS

```
SELECT SUM((case cost_price when 0 then price else cost_price end) * quantity)) as sum 
FROM `table` 
WHERE invoice = '1';
```

Comment: Case _expression_. (It has a return value.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `if` in MySQL (which is the rdbms according to the way you escape identifiers with backticks):

```
SELECT SUM(if(cost_price = 0, price, cost_price) * quantity) as sum
FROM `table` 
WHERE invoice = '1';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Sql Server you can use [IIF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-iif-transact-sql)

```
SELECT SUM(IIF(cost_price=0,price,cost_price) * quantity) AS SUM
FROM `table` 
WERE invoice = '1';
```

Comment: SQL Server and back-ticks?

Comment: @jarlh - I assumed that was a place holder for the table name.